# mysql - sum columns from multiple tables based on multiple id's

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum

I have a mySQL database with a couple of identical tables. I need to join all the tables and sum up the views and hits every time the `id1` and `id2` are equal in at least 2 tables, or simply show the row if not.

Please see below the tables structure:

```
Table1:
id..id2...views...hits
1...102...55......12
2...103...12......22

Table2:
id..id2...views...hits
1...123...512......13
2...103...123......43

Table3:
id..id2...views...hits
1...102...232......43
2...103...100......70
```

The end result should be the following table:

```
id...id2...views...hits
1....102...287....65   <-- This one is the result of adding 1st row of table1 and 2nd row of table 2
1....123...512....13   <-- This is the 1st row of table2 as there's no other id2 = 123
2....103...235....135 <-- This is the sum of 2nd row in table1 + 2nd row in table2 + 2nd row in table3
```

I hope this makes sense and someone can help with it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the rows of all three tables together with a union, then group and sum like usual:

```
SELECT id, id2, SUM(views), SUM(hits)
FROM
(
    SELECT id, id2, views, hits
    FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, id2, views, hits
    FROM Table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, id2, views, hits
    FROM Table3
) x
GROUP BY id, id2
```

Comment: ahhhh I'm an idiot ! I thought that wouldn't work because of the 2 ID's but you're right. Thanks a lot !

Comment: This syntax also works for SQLite, so that's awesome! Thank you for this answer, it helped me too!